# JS: Not been able to add the assertive arrays(dictionary) into their specific parent value

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I need to add the arrays that belong to parent[0], another for parent[1] and another for parent[2] ordered by size from 0 first then 1, then 2 then 3. I did an if statement but the mainParent0, mainParent1 and mainParent2 are still returning me an empty curly bracket {} instead of the arrays.

```
var categories = [
    { id: 1, parent: [0], size: 1 },
    { id: 2, parent: [0], size: 2 },
    { id: 3, parent: [1], size: 3 },
    { id: 4, parent: [2], size: 0 },
    { id: 5, parent: [1], size: 2 },
    { id: 6, parent: [1], size: 1 },
    { id: 7, parent: [1], size: 0 },
    { id: 8, parent: [2], size: 3 },
];
// 1st step making the parents into a variable 
let mainParent0 = {};
let mainParent1 = {};
let mainParent2 = {};
// 2nd step, adding the array that belong to each parent
for (var i = 0; i == parent[0]; i++){
    categories.push(categories[i].mainParent0)
}
if (categories[i] === 0) {
    categories.push(parent[0].mainParent0)
} 
if (categories[i] === 1) {
    categories.push(parent[1].mainParent1)
} 
if (categories[i] === 2) {
    categories.push(parent[2].mainParent2)
}
```

Comment: please add the wanted result. why is parent property an array? can an item have more than one parent?

Comment: wanted result would be ;

```
mainParent0 = [
{ id: 1, parent: [0], size: 1 },
{ id: 2, parent: [0], size: 2 }
]
mainParent1 = [
{ id: 7, parent: [1], size: 0 },
{ id: 6, parent: [1], size: 1 },
{ id: 5, parent: [1], size: 2 },
{ id: 3, parent: [1], size: 3 },
]
let mainParent2 = [
{ id: 4, parent: [2], size: 0 },
{ id: 8, parent: [2], size: 3 }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an object as result set and add the objects to the result set with the given parent value.

```js
var categories = [{ id: 1, parent: [0], size: 1 }, { id: 2, parent: [0], size: 2 }, { id: 3, parent: [1], size: 3 }, { id: 4, parent: [2], size: 0 }, { id: 5, parent: [1], size: 2 }, { id: 6, parent: [1], size: 1 }, { id: 7, parent: [1], size: 0 }, { id: 8, parent: [2], size: 3 }],
    parents = categories.reduce((r, o) => {
        o.parent.forEach(index => {
            (r[index] = r[index] || []).push(o);
            r[index].sort((a, b) => a.size - b.size);
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(parents);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```